# Divergence of a series similar to $\sum\frac{1}{p}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series

Suppose we start with $k$ primes $p_1,p_2,\ldots ,p_k$ (not necessarily consecutive) and a residue class for each prime $r_1,r_2,\ldots ,r_k$.
We denote the least integer not covered by the arithmetic progressions $r_i+m\cdot p_i$ as $r_{k+1}$ which is going to be the new residue class for a (random) prime $p_{k+1}$.
We proceed in this way "covering" the natural numbers (without changing the $r_i$'s.)
**Question**:Is it true that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r_n}=+\infty$?

**Motivation**:
This would directly imply Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions if we make use of this
 **Lemma**:
Let $a_n$ be a sequence of natural numbers, strictly increasing with $\gcd(a_i,a_j)=1$.
Then if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_n}=+\infty$ then the sequence contains infinitely many prime numbers.

I tried to modify some proofs which show the divergence of $\sum\frac{1}{p}$ but without much success.
Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT:** The primes are distinct and the residue classes are not reduced modulo $p$.Suppose we start with the primes $2,3,7$ and their residue classes are $(1)_2 , (2)_3 , (4)_7$ which means $r_1=1$, $r_2=2$ and $r_3=4$. The least number not covered by the progressions $1+2k , 2+3k , 4+7k$ is $6$.We define then $r_4=6$ and $6$ is going to be a new residue class for a new prime (random choice) let's say $p_4=17$.Then $r_5=10$ and we choose a new prime (Let's say $p_5=5$) and continue in this direction.
The $r_i$'s could be much greater than the $p_i$'s

Comment: How do you choose those "random" primes? Do you want this result to hold for each possible way to choose them? Are you assuming that each prime will be chosen eventually?

Comment: @Federico Poloni Yes I want in each possible way to hold and it is not necessary that all primes will appear.It is not that hard to prove that if the primes are "too big" (if the series of their reciprocals converges) then $\sum \frac{1}{r_n}=\infty$.But this is the easy case.

Comment: When you refer to the $r_i$'s as residue classes, do you mean that each is to be reduced modulo the corresponding $p_i$?  (Thus, we construct $r_{k + 1}$, choose $p_{k + 1}$, and then replace $r_{k + 1}$ by its reduction?)

Comment: I take it you are insisting the primes be distinct, else all you can say is the sum of the reciprocals could be 1.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The primes are distinct.

Comment: @LSpice of course no.The $r_i$'s are not reduced modulo $p_i$.It would be easy to answer the question then.

Comment: Since you are not reducing mod $p_i$, the term "residue class" is unnecessary (and perhaps counterproductive).  When you use that term, do you mean to say that $p_{k+1}$ is always chosen to be larger than $r_{k+1}$?

Comment: @S.Carnahan: in his first comment, KG says the case $\sum\frac{1}{p_n}<+\infty$ is easy. If $\sum\frac{1}{p_n}=+\infty$ and $r_n\le p_n$ for all $n$, then also $\sum\frac{1}{r_n}=+\infty$. So I guess the case of interest is when many $r_n$ are possibly larger than $p_n$.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: the integers $m$ in the definition of the arithmetic progressions are assumed to be $m\ge0$, right? thanks.

Comment: @PietroMajer yes $m\geq 0$

Comment: @S.Carnahan yes I know "residue class" sounds a bit weird since I am not reducing modp but I believe if I wrote something different then it would sound much more complicated.And $p_{k+1}$ is not chosen always larger than $r_{k+1}$.

Comment: Don't know how to prove your claim, but I like the lemma...

Comment: @Seva I was undergarduate when I proved it and I was sure it could have many applications,but I have not found anything nice so far.Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess if $(a_j)_j$ are pairwise relatively prime and only contain $n$ primes, then $\sum_j1/a_j\le 1+ \sum_{j=1}^n 1/p_j + \sum_{j=1}^\infty 1/p_j^2<+\infty$

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes of course this is true but I do not understand your point.

Comment: just a comment on the lemma :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson A nitpick: Konstantinos did say that there are $k$ of the primes which implies that they are distinct. But I agree that this is not the best way of saying it and could be considered ambiguous. But it's present in the literature unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The question makes sense if the $r$'s are all positive.  The answer is likely to be yes for
the folllowing reason: if it were no, there would be an explicit sequence where the
$r$'s grow faster than $O(1/f'(n))$, where $f(n)$ is smaller than any iterated $\log$ function,
and thus smaller than $\log \log\log\log\log n$, call this $\log_5 n$ or $g(n)$.  Current lower
bounds of the conceivable maximal
 growth rate of the $r$'s are like $$\dfrac1{g'(n)(\log_3 n)^2},$$ see recent work of Ford, Konyagin,
Green, Maynard, and Tao.  Having such a sequence of $r$'s and $p$'s would allow one to
radically improve on this bound, for one could leverage this to find really large gaps
between primes.

Of related interest may be Kanolds work in 1963-65 on such sequences of $r$'s. If the
$r$'s grow slowly enough (something like $n^{2-c}$), one can get [Linnik's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem) on the
least prime in arithmetic progressions as well as a non-quantitative version of
[Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) through elementary means.